# Assigns clause for local variables in Frama-C

Tags: frama-c

I am trying to verify the following piece of code using frama-c

```
/*@ ensures \result != \null; 
  @ assigns \nothing;
  @*/
extern int *new_value();

//@ assigns *p;
void f(int* p){
  *p = 8;
}
//@ assigns \nothing;
int main(void){
 int *p = new_value(); 
 f(p);
}
```

The prover is unable to prove that *main* assigns \nothing, which makes sense, as *main* assigns to *p through function *f*. However, how should I state that in \assigns clause, since *p* is local variable and can not be accessed within annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `assigns nothing` is indeed false. The variable `p` is local but the effect is done on `*p` which is an arbitrary pointer.

### Counterexample

If `new_value` is defined as the following:

```
int g;

int *new_value(){
  return &g;
}
```

It satisfies the specification and the value of `g` is `8` at the end of the main.

### To go further

If the problem is to be able to give an assign to the function main without any knowledge of the behavior of the function `new_value`, you can make the result of `new_value` accessible from the logic space:

For instance :

```
//@ logic int * R ;
//@ ensures \result == R && \valid(R) ; assigns \nothing ;
extern int *new_value();

//@ assigns *p;
void f(int * p) { … }

//@ assigns *R ;
int main(void) { … }
```

A more general solution would be to have a set of pointer for R, instead of a unique one.

Comment: thanks for the answer. When using wp plugin, it breaks. Now I'm installing Jessie plugin to see if it works. Which one did you use?

Comment: Tried with Jessie. I had to put declaration of R into axiomatic block. Afterwards, I got typing error: unbound identifier R. @François, you don't have similar problem? Which version of Jessie do you use?

Comment: sorry for confusion, there was some other technical problem. The idea with introducing logical R works with wp.